# Hash object limit on number of keys - large recursive lookup [SAS]

Tags: hash, sas

I am using a hash object for recursive lookup.

Example data

```
id1    id2
A      B
B      C
C      D
```

Output

```
orig_id    id1     id2
A          A       B
A          B       C
A          C       D
```

I am having no issues with my recursive lookup using a hash object.

Rather, my **Question** is **is there a practical limit to the number of keys in a hash object**?

More context - I have over 10 million records of `id1 id2`. These are randomly generated unique identifiers for each record. Therefore, for recursive lookup, I need all pairs of ids in my hash object. My understanding of hash objects is that `2^20` is the upper limit of hash keys, but I do not receive any warnings or errors when I load my table of id-pairs as a hash object.

Alternatively, if a hash object is truly capped at `2^20` hash keys, is there an alternative way to perform a recursive lookup? I've tried looking into *data access functions* but was unable to find a function like `locatec` or `locaten` that would return the row number of an observation that satisfied a condition. Is there a function I'm missing that works like `locatec` but returns a row number?

Comment: That actual limit is how much memory you have to store the hash.  The number of buckets used for initial hashing only has an impact on how long it takes to find a value in the hash.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Makes me question whether I have any idea of how a hash table works, but it also makes me feel a lot better about using the hash object.